# Абстрактный класс возвращает свой экземпляр

Tags: java

Есть абстрактный класс, а в нём метод `getSmallClone(double i)` который должен возвращать объект такого абстрактного класса(его наследника).

Компилятор хочет что бы я сразу реализовал абстрактный метод, но этого сделать невозможно же. Как быть?

```
abstract class AbstractFigure {
    abstract boolean inFigure(Point point);

    AbstractFigure getSmallClone(double i) {
          return new AbstractFigure(st, en);
    }
}
```

Comment: Причина в том, что нельзя создать объект абстрактного класса. Мешает то, что есть абстрактный метод, который необходимо перед созданием объекта определить, соответсвенно

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_%28%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%29 ?

Comment: Я думаю, Вам могут пригодиться дженерики и конструкция типа `<? super E>` (где в качестве E будет AbstractFigure) для реализации того, что вы хотите сделать.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Это действительно невозможно, экземпляр абстрактного класса невозможно создать.

Вы должны каким-либо образом вернуть конкретный дочерний класс, в котором абстрактный метод получит имплементацию.

Для этого вы либо должны сделать метод `getSmallClone` также абстрактным (и имплементировать его в наследниках), либо создать производный класс «на месте»:

```
return new AbstractFigure(st, en) {
    @Override
    boolean inFigure(Point point) {
        // тут какая-нибудь подходящая имплементация, например:
        return AbstractFigure.this.inFigure(point);
    }
};
```

Выбирайте тот путь, который правильнее для вашей программы. Исходя из названия `getSmallClone`, возможно, вам нужен второй путь. Тут уж решайте сами.

Comment: либо сделать его статичным и создавать в нем наследников

Answer (score 4):

> Абстрактный класс в объектно-ориентированном программировании —
>   базовый класс, который не предполагает создания экземпляров.

[Википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81)

```
public abstract class AbstractFigure {
    protected abstract AbstractFigure getSmallClone(double i);
}

public class Figure extends AbstractFigure {
    @Override
    public Figure getSmallClone(double i) {
        return /*...  */;
    }
}
```